# Separar frases em uma String

Tags: java, string

Tenho essa String com um espaço entre o título(maiúsculo) e a descrição:

> REMETIDOS OS AUTOS PARA DISTRIBUIDOR
>   Baixa novamente

O código:

```
final String linha = row.getCell(3).getTextContent().replaceAll("\t","").replaceAll("\n","").trim()
```

Porém preciso pegar o título e a descrição separadas, para que fiquem assim:

String **titulo** :REMETIDOS OS AUTOS PARA DISTRIBUIDOR

String **descricao**: Baixa novamente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É só cortar a string em dois pedaços. O primeiro sendo do início da string original até a quebra de linha e o segundo a partir da quebra de linha até o final da string.

Perceba que eu usei [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) para definir qual o carácter de quebra de linha definido pelo sistema operacional, pois isto varia de um sistema pra outro.

Isso é possível de duas maneiras:

#### 1. Usando o método `split` para quebrar a string em um *array*

Note que usando esta abordagem, a *string* vai ser quebrada em todo lugar que for encontrada uma quebra de linha, isso pode ser um efeito indesejável (ou pode ser justamente o que procura).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator();

        String str = "REMETIDOS OS AUTOS PARA DISTRIBUIDOR" + lineSeparator +
                     "Baixa novamente";

        String[] arr = str.split(lineSeparator);
        String titulo = arr[0];
        String descricao = arr[1];            

        System.out.println(titulo);
        System.out.println(descricao);
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/Kk9I/4)

#### 2. Usando o método `substring()`

Usando esta abordagem é possível definir como se comportar no caso de várias quebras de linhas.

**Explicação do código:**

A variável `index` guarda qual a posição da **última quebra de linha** dentro da *string* principal.

`str.substring(0, index)` retorna uma nova *string* contendo um pedaço da *string* original, desde o início (índice 0) até o valor de `index`.

`str.substring(index + lineSeparator.length())` retorna uma nova *string* a partir da quebra de linha da *string* original **mais o tamanho da quebra de linha** (em alguns sistemas a quebra de linha pode ser representada por dois carácteres), isso para ignorar a quebra de linha nas novas *strings*.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator();

        String str = "REMETIDOS OS AUTOS PARA DISTRIBUIDOR" + lineSeparator +
                     "Baixa novamente";

        int index = str.lastIndexOf(lineSeparator);

        String titulo = str.substring(0, index);
        String descricao = str.substring(index + lineSeparator.length());

        System.out.println(titulo);
        System.out.println(descricao);
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/Kk9I/3)

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço muito de *java*, mas em *javascript* eu utilizaria um `split`, sendo o parâmetro `\t`. 
Realizando desta forma:

```
var stringUm   = parametro.split(/\t/)[0]
var stringDois = parametro.split(/\t/)[1]
```

Dessa forma eu teria duas *strings* separadas pela quebra de linha.

Se houver um método para realizar `split` no *java* utilize-o para resolver seu problema.